# React onClick function only fires once upon rendering to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I have the following example of a React component that renders tags to the DOM based on the component's state. The intention is to remove the `item` from the state's `tags` array once the `delete_tag` anchor is clicked. For now, I've just set it to alert the user.

```
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      el: 'times',
      tags: ['dog', 'cat']
    };
  },

  render: function () {
    let that = this;
    return (
      <div id={this.state.el}>
        <div className="center-form">
          <div className="tag_div">
            { this.state.tags.map(function(item) {
                return (
                <div className="tag">
                  {item}
                  <a className="delete_tag" onClick={alert(item)}></a>
                </div>
                );
              })
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Using the above code, immediately before every tag is rendered, the user gets alerted. Afterwards, the tags render, but the `delete_tag` anchor does not respond to any clicks.

I found this odd given that other functions in this component, being used in a similar way with `onClick={that.function()}` seem to work as intended. **Why isn't this `onClick` attribute behaving as expected?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `onClick` a function. The value you passed - `alert(item)` - is not a function, it's just an invocation of `alert`.

Instead, you want:

```
onClick={function () { alert(item); }}
```

Or if you're using ES6:

```
onClick={() => alert(item)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change onClick to:

`... onClick={function(){ alert(item); }} ...`

This should work because now you give function which will be called as onClick callback. In your version it is called imediatelly and  onClick have nothing as callback